# Given that there is no derivative at an undefined point, how can l'Hospital's rule be valid for left/right-hand limits of boundary points?

Tags: calculus

I don't understand how l'Hospital's rule can be valid for one-sided limits of boundary points $a$ and $b$ when its stated for functions, say $f$ and $g$, that are differentiable on an open interval, say $(a, b)$. Must not points be defined for there to be derivatives there? Given that $a$ and $b$ aren't defined, how can we even evaluate

$$\lim_{x\to a+}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$

when $a$, and therefore $f'(a)$ and $g'(a)$, are undefined?

Sorry if my question is bad, it is my first here on the forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule is not telling you that any of $f'(c), g'(c), f(c), g(c)$ exists. It is just saying that some two limits agree, under certain circumstances. An easy example: we take $f(x) = g(x) = 2x+\sin(x)$ and $c = \infty$. Of course it does not make sense to evaluate $2x+\sin(x)$ or its derivative $2+\cos(x)$ at infinity. But the expression $\frac{2x+\sin(x)}{2x+\sin(x)}$, which is constantly equal to $1$ on $(0,\infty)$, clearly has a limit at infinity, namely $1$, which is the same limit as for $\frac{2+\cos(x)}{2+\cos(x)}$.

You could also take $c=0$: the limit of $\frac{2x+\sin(x)}{2x+\sin(x)}$ at $0$ is $1$ (even though both numerator and denominator go to zero). And on the quotient of the derivatives you see it even more clearly, since $\frac{2+\cos(x)}{2+\cos(x)}$ is even defined at $0$.

A conclusive remark which might sound obvious but I think is quite important: when you apply L'Hôpital's rule, usually the function in which you're interested is neither $f$ nor $g$, but rather their quotient $\frac{f}{g}$. That's a function in its own right whenever it is defined, and it is its behaviour that you want to study, not the one of $f$ or $g$.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing with limits, is that we don’t care about what $f(a)$ **exactly** equals for calculating the value of $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$, say. Limits only deal with what value a function approaches (if any) as the input variable gets closer and closer to some value.

Further, it’s important to decide which side of the limit we are interested in. In your question, it’s explicitly specified that we’re evaluating the right hand limit. Another way to think of this limit is to ask,

What is $\frac{f’(a+h)}{g’(a+h)}$, when $h$ is infinitesimally small? Note this is not equal to $\frac{f’(a)}{g’(a)}$, however small $h$ is.

Answer (score 0):

By my count, there are 75 versions of l'Hospital's Rule. In all the versions involving limits as $x$ approaches a real number $a$ there is no problem wih $a$ itself. (We are not talking about $x \to \infty \text { or }x \to -\infty.$)The number  $a \quad IS \quad$defined. There is no need for any of $f(a),g(a),f'(a),g'(a)$ to exist. All that is required is for the expressions $f(x),g(x),f'(x),g'(x)$ to exist on some open interval $(a,b).$   Neither is it required to attach any meaning to the symbols $f(a)/g(a) \text { or } f'(a)/g'(a).$ All that is required is $g(x),g'(x)$ to be non-zero on $(a,b).$ Nor is there any requirement about the limits of $f'(x)$ or $g'(x)$ as $x \to a^+$.  All that l'Hospital's Rule says  is that if certain conditions hold for the limits of $ f(x) \text{ and }g(x)$ as $x \to a^+$ then if something can be said about the limit of $f'(x)/g'(x)$ as $x \to a^+$ then the same can be said about the limit of $f(x)/g(x)$ as $x \to a^+$.